# Applying an Import Range function in Google Sheets without exceeding number of rows and columns

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Pretty Self explanatory. In Google Sheets I need a workaround to this limitation. What I need in short is to feed a Sheets workbook every time the raw data gets updated in another file.

The problem is if I use an Import Range function, it will eventually exceed the number of rows or columns currently available an bring me an error, and since I need this to automatize a process, having to each time add more rows or columns manually defeats the purpose.

Comment: Automatically adding rows and columns is unfortunately not a feature of google sheets alone. You can use Google Apps Script as a workaround for this issue. Can you share with us the ImportRange function that you have used that exceeded the number of rows and columns so that we may try it out on Google Apps Script?

Comment: Why not you add more more rows first then use import range.

Comment: The formula is =IMPORTRANGE("urlwithrawdatagoeshere","A:A") the error that it brings is 113068. I need the range to be A:A because the raw data file is always being updated and more rows are added every week.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTRANGE("id"; "sheet1!A:Z"); 50; 25)
```

where `50` can be `ROWS(A:A)-ROW()+1` and `25` can be `COLUMNS(1:1)-COLUMN()+1`

Comment: Right but this wouldn't solve my issue. I need it to update every time the linked file with the raw data gets more information added. As someone else said before, would I need then to use an App Script to solve this?